# how to display image from database in asp.net c# .I am creating signup where user has to upload hi image

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
/*path to get image and to display it.... */

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;   

namespace Uogchatear2
{
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                uogChatearDataContext db = new uogChatearDataContext();
                    var getpic = (from i in db.tbl_Profilepics where i.userId == 12 select i).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (getpic!=null)
                    {
                        Imagebig.ImageUrl = getpic.imagepath;  /*image path to display image*/
                        Imagesmall.ImageUrl = getpic.imagepath;
                        imgtry.Src = getpic.imagepath;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any error your are getting?? if you save your image on server and save your path in database properly then you can display it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it is not very clear if you are saving the image data in some file or the database it self.

If you are saving in file, then easiest option probably will be to save them in a path which is publicly accessible from web, through a url. You'll have to set the permission of that path to be writable by IIS users.

If you are saving the image binary in db then you have two major options:

1. use a helper url that can read image from db and write the binary to the response. Clean technique will be to write a HTTP handler (.axd), instead of using a Page (aspx). Read the image binary data from database and store in a byte array, then use Response.BinaryWrite() method with content type set to "images/xxx", where xxx will be the type of image: jpg, png, gif etc.
2. Use Base64 encoded data to display image, if the images uploaded won't be very large. Note that since these images will be part of html itself, base64 encoded image can cause delay in html loading depending upon their size.

We can discuss further if any of above mentioned points are not clear or confusing.

Update:

Again taking a second look at your code, it seems more likely that you are saving image in a file. So, you'll have to mention what exactly is the problem you are facing with image. Is there some problem while saving image? Is image saved but not loading on browser? Or, you can simply set the value of column "imagepath" to store base64 data URI representation of the image.